# Is model validation, based on controller action, possible in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a class library project containing the model with validation annotations on some properties, which I use in a Web API project, f.x.

```
class Product
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int Barcode { get; set; }
}
```

I would very much like to "disable" or "remove" a validation attribute on my model, before model validation, if the action is create.

So if the action is...

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<Product>>> Create([FromBody] Product product)
{
    // Do work...
}
```

I wan't to ignore the `Required` validation on ProductId.

Is this possible, and if so how would one go about this?

Thank you very much for any input.

Comment: What about using `ModelState.Remove("ProductId ")`?

Comment: Where would one do that, so it happens before model validation?

Comment: No.I don't think ignore required validation for specific action before model validation is a good choice.If you must do that I think you could did it in model binding and remove the modestate for the ProductId.I think the quick way is to create a new view model with no required attribute on ProductId.Or you could put `ModelState.Remove("ProductId ")` in the Create action to ignore the model validation.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but code execution never enters the action when model validation fails. So `ModelState.Remove("ProductId")` in the Create action will never be reached. Edited: But yes removing it in the model binding, through a custom model binder, would be a way to go.